# Maximum and Minimum Values using Trigonometric Functions: $f(t)=t-2\cos(t)$ for $t\in[-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

**RESOLVED**

How would I go about finding the maximum and minimum values for an expression I cannot factor to find zeros?

I have some function:

$$f(t)=t-2\cos(t)$$

With the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$.

I would like to know how to find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum values specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and your answer above, I assume you understand the process of finding absolute extreme and are just having trouble with finding the critical values. We found the derivative to be $f(t)=1+2sin(t)$, and by definition of critical numbers we want to see when this is equal to zero. Rearranging, we have $sin(t)=-1/2$, and now we have to use our knowledge of the unit circle. We are really trying to think backwards, and ask ourselves the sin of what, or in other words $t=arcsin(-1/2)$. This gives us $t=-5\pi/6$, and $t=\pi/6$. From now follow tips given by Mark to find the extreme points.

Comment: Thank you. This is the part I wanted answered most. Very great explanation!

Comment: Only I understand that $\sin^{-1}(-1/2)$ is equivalent to $-\pi/6$... where does the $-5\pi/6$ come into play?

Comment: If you imagine the unit circle, $-\pi/6$ and $-5\pi/6$ are both the same vertical distance from the x-axis, just reflected along the y-axis, so they both have a sin value of -1/2. In fact, since all sin functions are periodic, we can have $-\pi/6 +k$, where $k$ is any integer, and it would have a sin value equal to -1/2. However we can neglect those solutions since we only look in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$f'(t)=1+2\sin(t)=0$$

when $t=-\pi/6$ and $t=-5\pi/6$.

At which of these values of $t$ is $f(t)$ a local maximum?

What are the values of $f(t)$ at the end points $-\pi$ and $\pi$?

Comment: $-\pi/6$... But I do not know how you derived these numbers

Comment: $\sin(t)=-1/2$ when $t=-\pi/6$ and $t=-5\pi//6$.

Comment: And how do I know that $\sin(t)$ is equal to $-1/2$ at $-\pi/6$ and $-5\pi/6$?

Comment: I forgot to mention these should be absolute maximums not local maximums/minimums

Comment: That's the reason for my asking in the HINT "What are the values of $f(t)$ at the end points $-\pi$ and $\pi$?"

Comment: I do not understand how I am supposed to answer that. That is what I am trying to find out. Wouldn't I plug it in $f(t)$ to find this out? I ask this because I am not getting the answer I expect.

Comment: @Computer `how I am supposed to answer that` $f(-\pi)=-\pi-2\cos(-\pi)=-\pi+2\,$, $f(\pi)=\pi-2 \cos(\pi)=\pi+2\,$.

Comment: Except the absolute minimum of $-\pi+2$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Computer Your apparent assumption that the global minimum must somehow be at $-\pi$ is incorrect. You have $4$ values to check, $2$ critical points plus $2$ endpoints of the interval.

Comment: Ah, that is where I went wrong. But, I am still stuck on finding critical points for trigonometric functions. He said $-\pi/6$ and $-5\pi/6$ which I do not understand how he got.